# Jquery Placeholder Inaccurate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flexbox, jquery-ui-sortable

So I am using jquery-ui sortable on a flex layout to create a grid that can be reordered by dragging and dropping.

What happens most of the time is when the cursor was moving down last the placeholder appears on the right and when the cursor was moved up last the placeholder appears on the left.

What I want is the placeholder to be in the gap closest to where the cursor is.

Here is a simplified version of what I have.

```js
$('#sortable').sortable({
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  helper: 'clone',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.show();
    $('.block-totara-featured-links-layout').sortable('option', 'cursorAt', {
      left: ui.item.width() / 2,
      top: ui.item.height() / 2
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#sortable{
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#sortable div {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #f00;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
#sortable div.placeholder {
  max-width: 4px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-right: -2px;
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="sortable">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by extending the sortable widget and hacking some of the methods to recognise whether the pointer is on the left or right of an item.

Ill post the code here so people can get an idea of what I did

```js
$.widget('custom.sortableGrid', $.ui.sortable, { // A Hack of the base code so it puts the place holder in the right place
        _onRightSide: function(item, event){
            return  this._isOverAxis(
                event.pageX,
                item.left + ( item.width / 2 ),
                item.width / 2
            );
        },
        _intersectsWithPointer: function( item ) {
            var verticalDirection, horizontalDirection,
                isOverElementHeight = ( this.options.axis === "x" ) ||
                    this._isOverAxis(
                        this.positionAbs.top + this.offset.click.top, item.top, item.height ),
                isOverElementWidth = ( this.options.axis === "y" ) ||
                    this._isOverAxis(
                        this.positionAbs.left + this.offset.click.left, item.left, item.width ),
                isOverElement = isOverElementHeight && isOverElementWidth;

            if ( !isOverElement ) {
                return false;
            }

            verticalDirection = this._getDragVerticalDirection();
            horizontalDirection = this._getDragHorizontalDirection();

            return (horizontalDirection === "right" || verticalDirection === "down" ) ? 2 : 1;

        },
        _mouseDrag: function(event) {
            var i, item, itemElement, intersection,
                o = this.options,
                scrolled = false;

            //Compute the helpers position
            this.position = this._generatePosition( event );
            this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo( "absolute" );

            if ( !this.lastPositionAbs ) {
                this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
            }

            //Do scrolling
            if ( this.options.scroll ) {
                if ( this.scrollParent[ 0 ] !== this.document[ 0 ] &&
                    this.scrollParent[ 0 ].tagName !== "HTML" ) {

                    if ( ( this.overflowOffset.top + this.scrollParent[ 0 ].offsetHeight ) -
                        event.pageY < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollTop =
                            scrolled = this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollTop + o.scrollSpeed;
                    } else if ( event.pageY - this.overflowOffset.top < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollTop =
                            scrolled = this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollTop - o.scrollSpeed;
                    }

                    if ( ( this.overflowOffset.left + this.scrollParent[ 0 ].offsetWidth ) -
                        event.pageX < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollLeft = scrolled =
                            this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollLeft + o.scrollSpeed;
                    } else if ( event.pageX - this.overflowOffset.left < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollLeft = scrolled =
                            this.scrollParent[ 0 ].scrollLeft - o.scrollSpeed;
                    }

                } else {

                    if ( event.pageY - this.document.scrollTop() < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        scrolled = this.document.scrollTop( this.document.scrollTop() - o.scrollSpeed );
                    } else if ( this.window.height() - ( event.pageY - this.document.scrollTop() ) <
                        o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        scrolled = this.document.scrollTop( this.document.scrollTop() + o.scrollSpeed );
                    }

                    if ( event.pageX - this.document.scrollLeft() < o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        scrolled = this.document.scrollLeft(
                            this.document.scrollLeft() - o.scrollSpeed
                        );
                    } else if ( this.window.width() - ( event.pageX - this.document.scrollLeft() ) <
                        o.scrollSensitivity ) {
                        scrolled = this.document.scrollLeft(
                            this.document.scrollLeft() + o.scrollSpeed
                        );
                    }

                }

                if ( scrolled !== false && $.ui.ddmanager && !o.dropBehaviour ) {
                    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets( this, event );
                }
            }

            //Regenerate the absolute position used for position checks
            this.positionAbs = this._convertPositionTo( "absolute" );

            //Set the helper position
            if ( !this.options.axis || this.options.axis !== "y" ) {
                this.helper[ 0 ].style.left = this.position.left + "px";
            }
            if ( !this.options.axis || this.options.axis !== "x" ) {
                this.helper[ 0 ].style.top = this.position.top + "px";
            }

            //Rearrange
            for ( i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {


                //Cache variables and intersection, continue if no intersection
                item = this.items[ i ];
                itemElement = item.item[ 0 ];
                intersection = this._intersectsWithPointer( item );
                if ( !intersection ) {
                    continue;
                }

                this.direction = this._onRightSide(item, event) === true ? "right" : "left";
                this._rearrange( event, item );


                if (!this._intersectsWithSides(item)) {
                    break;
                }

                this._trigger( "change", event, this._uiHash() );
                break;
            }

            //Post events to containers
            this._contactContainers( event );

            //Interconnect with droppables
            if ( $.ui.ddmanager ) {
                $.ui.ddmanager.drag( this, event );
            }

            //Call callbacks
            this._trigger( "sort", event, this._uiHash() );

            this.lastPositionAbs = this.positionAbs;
            return false;

        },
        _rearrange: function( event, i, a, hardRefresh ) {
            a ? a[ 0 ].appendChild( this.placeholder[ 0 ] ) :
                i.item[ 0 ].parentNode.insertBefore(
                    this.placeholder[ 0 ],
                    ( this.direction === "left" ? i.item[ 0 ] : i.item[ 0 ].nextSibling )
                );

            //Various things done here to improve the performance:
            // 1. we create a setTimeout, that calls refreshPositions
            // 2. on the instance, we have a counter variable, that get's higher after every append
            // 3. on the local scope, we copy the counter variable, and check in the timeout,
            // if it's still the same
            // 4. this lets only the last addition to the timeout stack through
            this.counter = this.counter ? ++this.counter : 1;
            var counter = this.counter;

            this._delay( function() {
                if ( counter === this.counter ) {

                    //Precompute after each DOM insertion, NOT on mousemove
                    this.refreshPositions( !hardRefresh );
                }
            } );

        }
    });
```